# Add new element to an existing object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I was looking for a way to add new elements to an an existing object like what push does with arrays

I have tried this and it didn't work :

```
var myFunction = {
    Author: 'my name ',
    date: '15-12-2012',
    doSomething: function(){
        alert("helloworld")
    }
};
myFunction.push({
    bookName:'mybook',
    bookdesc: 'new'
});
console.log(myFunction);
```

Comment: `myFunction` is an object. Objects don't have a `push` method. (neither do functions)

Comment: I know this is old, but it seems at least a little confusing to name a variable myFunction.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use this:

```
myFunction.bookName = 'mybook';
myFunction.bookdesc = 'new';
```

Or, if you are using jQuery:

```
$(myFunction).extend({
    bookName:'mybook',
    bookdesc: 'new'
});
```

The `push` method is wrong because it belongs to the `Array.prototype` object.

To create a named object, try this:

```
var myObj = function(){
    this.property = 'foo';
    this.bar = function(){
    }
}
myObj.prototype.objProp = true;
var newObj = new myObj();
```

Comment: thanks that sounds good , but my other question about how can we give a name to the object

Comment: What name? Could you explain better?

Comment: when you do a console.log(yourObject) it comes up as named object how can we change that display name ?

Comment: `myFunction.bookdesc = 'new';` helped me Thanks

Answer (score 14):

Just do `myFunction.foo = "bar"` and it will add it. `myFunction` is the name of the object in this case.

Answer (score 6):

jQuery syntax mentioned above by Danilo Valente is not working. It should be as following-

```
$.extend(myFunction,{
    bookName:'mybook',
    bookdesc: 'new'
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) to add new objects to an existing one.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the [jQuery extend method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/). This will allow you to add other members to your already created JS object.

Comment: This is also available in lodash: https://lodash.com/docs#isEmpty : _.isEmpty({ 'a': 1 }); // → false

Answer (score 2):

You could store your JSON inside of an array and then insert the JSON data into the array with `push`

Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/cx2rk40e/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // using jQuery just to load function but will work without library.
  $( "button" ).on( "click", go );

  // Array of JSON we will append too.
  var jsonTest = [{
    "colour": "blue",
    "link": "http1"
  }]

  // Appends JSON to array with push. Then displays the data in alert.
  function go() {    
      jsonTest.push({"colour":"red", "link":"http2"});
      alert(JSON.stringify(jsonTest));    
    }

});
```

Result of `JSON.stringify(jsonTest)`

```
[{"colour":"blue","link":"http1"},{"colour":"red","link":"http2"}]
```

This answer maybe useful to users who wish to emulate a similar result.