# how to add multiple items to an object in javascript

Tags: javascript

im writting a ShoppingCart class to add and remove items from the cart
code is meant to add and remove items from the shopping cart.

```
class ShoppingCart{
  constructor(){
    this.total = 0;
    this.items = {};
  }

  addItems(itemName, quantity, price){
    this.itemName = itemName;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.price = price;
    this.cost = this.quantity * this.price;

    this.total += this.cost;

    this.items['itemName'] = this.itemName;
    this.items['quantity'] = this.quantity;
  }

  removeItems(itemName, quantity, price){
    this.itemName = itemName;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.price = price;
    this.cost = this.quantity * this.price;

    this.total -= this.cost;
    delete this.items['itemName', 'quantity'];
  }
}
```

Comment: where are you stuck?

Comment: maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14234646/adding-elements-to-object/14234701

Comment: your code already looks broken. class variables are not declared

Comment: The question, as it stands, doesn't actually ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need how to add and remove list items.

follow below approach and let me know if it works for you.

```
<ul id="todo"></ul>
<button onclick="addItemTodo('test')">Add</button>
```

js

```
function addItemTodo(text) {
list = document.getElementById("todo");

item = document.createElement('li');
item.innerText = text;

trash = document.createElement('button');
trash.classList.add('btn1');
trash.addEventListener("click", removeActivity);

icon_trash = document.createElement('i');
icon_trash.classList.add('fas', 'fa-trash-alt', 'fa-2x');
item.appendChild(trash);
trash.appendChild(icon_trash);

list.appendChild(item); }
 function removeActivity() {
var listItems = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    listItems[i].onclick = function() {
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    }
  }
  }
```

[Live demo](https://codepen.io/shahidali/pen/NzrMXy)