# How to insert data to JSON file dynamically?

Tags: json, typescript, httpclient, angular6

[json file img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1r5qH.png)

Note: I wanna insert data without write that into .json file. such as Angularfire2 database.

```
 user = {
 name: 'Arthur',
 age: 21
};

const options = {Headers, responseType: 'json' as 'blob'};
    this.httpService.put('assets/data/ex.json', this.user, options).subscribe(
      data => {
         console.log(data);
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log (err.message);
      }
    );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding elements to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14234646/adding-elements-to-object)

Comment: Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: How to save this data in file json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly access the object using dot operator

```
user = {
 name: 'Arthur',
 age: 21
};

const options = {Headers, responseType: 'json' as 'blob'};
    this.httpService.put('assets/data/ex.json', this.user, options).subscribe(
      data => {
         console.log(data);
```

> data.user.lastName = 'stackoverflow';

```
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log (err.message);
      }
    );
```

Comment: how to save data in json file

Comment: To perform write operation you may need file system module in place. without that it wont be possible to do with angular. Try checking with file system module here is the [link](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

Comment: can you tell how to connect node.js with angular 6