# Add data in Object Array

Tags: javascript

So, I have an input, I enter words for filter answers.
My answers are my panel.
I create an Array for register my answers.

```
var array = [];
```

But when I finish my loop, I want to innerHTML my datas who are in my Array. 
But I have a [object HTMLDivElement] because i push Object in Array. 
Ok my question is = How can I create an Array Object and push my panel in

```
var obj = {}
```

And How can I display them
This code search in answer if the words exist

```
if (searchIndex > -1) {
```

If the answer exist , push the panel in my array and count how many answer he founds

```
    array.push(panel);
    countFound++;
}
```

When the loop is finish, exploit this data and display them

```
array1.forEach(function(element) {
   // I dont know how is the method to exploit all data one by one
});
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: That isn't an error. It looks like `panel` is a DOM element, a <div> specifically.

Comment: Ok i will reformul my problem, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what your HTML looks like, you should use `innerHTML` attribute to get the contents of an element.

```
array.push(panel.innerHTML);
```

You get the `object HTMLDivElement` because that's what `panel` is.

If you want to iterate over the elements in `array` you can do it with a [foor loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp), alternative with a [foreach loop](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp), and to display it again in the HTML you once again need to use the `innerHTML` attribute.

```
text = "";
for (i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
    text += array[I];
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = text;
```

And of you want to repeat the procedure you need to empty the `array` variable afterwards:

```
array = []; // Add this line after appending your data to the HTML.
            // Realistically after the for loop
```

Comment: and for loop my array, for display my data, how  I can doing that plz ?

Comment: @Khyra You're asking a separate question that requires some knowledge about your HTML. Do you want to display it on a web page? Do you have a specific HTML element that you want it to be shown in?

Comment: Yes I have a lot of questions, a lot of problems with my code because Im not an expert in all language. 

Hmm yes I want to display my data in a web page html. I will show you my code

Comment: @Khyra I updated my answer to include how to display the data in the HTML again.

Comment: yes ok i see what you mean, compare with my version, Im in right or im totally out with my code for display the array ? Thx for take your time

Comment: @Khyra It seems you need to empty the array afterwards. I have added this in my answer. Otherwise your implementation looks ok. Also - it's better to update your question instead of adding additional information in an answer.

Comment: Yes I understand the things, and I try to do it, but I dont know do it ... 
I put afterwards like you said, after my for an empty array but I dont know why the array is not empty

Answer (score 1):

For more Details go to [adding-elements-to-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14234646/adding-elements-to-object)
Here is how it works:

```js
var element = {}, cart = [];
element.id = 1;
element.panel = document.getElementById("panel");

cart.push(element);

alert(cart[0].panel);
```

```html
<div id="panel"></div>
```