# Use of prototype in below example Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

While going through the concepts of prototype. I saw below example from stackoverflow - [Add new element to an existing object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057802/add-new-element-to-an-existing-object/11057849#11057849)

```
var myObj = function(){
    this.property = 'foo';
    this.bar = function(){
    }
}

myObj.prototype.objProp = true;
var newObj = new myObj();
```

My question is what is the use of "`myObj.prototype.objProp = true;`" from above code snippet.

I am an beginner. Already referred other post similar to this. But couldn't make out.

Any help on this will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What *do* you understand about the prototype? There's nothing particularly special about this specific use; re-explaining everything about the prototype won't be particularly productive, that's already been done to death.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prototype is used for having common values in similar objects. you property `objProp` is available for all objects but does not belong to anyone.

When you do `myObj.objProp`, `objProp` is searched inside `myObj`. If not found, property is searched in `__proto__`.

Also note that if you define a property of same name inside object, like `myObj.objProp`, it will add a property in that object and not override **proto** one

```js
var myObj = function(){
    this.property = 'foo';
    this.bar = function(){
    }
}

myObj.prototype.objProp = true;
var newObj = new myObj();

console.log(newObj);

console.log(newObj.objProp);
```