# how to add nested object with new object

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, object

Actually, I want to add hats object to clothing object, i don't want to change object to array of object.
Can anyone help me how to add hats in my scenario.

```
const clothing = {
shirts:{
id: 1,
title: 'shirts' ,
item: [
  {
    id: 01,
    name:'plain shirt',
  },
  {
    id: 02,
    name: 'stripe shirt',
  },
 ],
},

tshirt: {
id: 2,
title: 't-shirt',
item: [
  {
    id: 03,
    name: 'plain t-shirt',
  },
  {
    id: 04,
    name: 'stripe t-shirt',
   }
  ],
 },
}

const newClothing = {...clothing};
newClothing[{hats:{id:3, title:'hats', item:[{id:05, name:'blue hats'}]}}];

console.log(newClothing.hats);
```

Comment: clothing.hats = your hats.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add new element to an existing object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057802/add-new-element-to-an-existing-object)

Comment: `{...clothing};`  A little warning, that will only do a shallow copy, so if your expecting a full copy for newClothing that won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simplest way you can do it:

```
const newClothing = {...clothing, hats: { ...your hats object here } };
```

Comment: No problem :) :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, I don't think you need to do anything fancy here. Simply add a property as follows:

```
clothing.hats = {
    id:3, 
    title:'hats', 
    item:[{id:05, name:'blue hats'}]
   }
```

Comment: Thank you bro..for answering ..and it is solved..

Answer (score 1):

Use . notation to add the hats object

```js
const clothing = {
shirts:{
id: 1,
title: 'shirts' ,
item: [
  {
    id: 01,
    name:'plain shirt',
  },
  {
    id: 02,
    name: 'stripe shirt',
  },
 ],
},

tshirt: {
id: 2,
title: 't-shirt',
item: [
  {
    id: 03,
    name: 'plain t-shirt',
  },
  {
    id: 04,
    name: 'stripe t-shirt',
   }
  ],
 },
}


clothing.hats={id:3, title:'hats', item:[{id:05, name:'blue hats'}]};
console.log(clothing.hats);
```