# How to add objects from existing JSON to an empty object in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object

I am trying to take JSON data information from a separate file and insert that info into a newly created object. I know there are a lot of similar questions, but how do you do this with **Node JS**? I've tried just about all the options from the following link with no success

[Add new element to an existing object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057802/add-new-element-to-an-existing-object)

Ex:

```
"EXTERNAL-DATA" : [
  {
    "clients" {
        {
            "firstName" : "Thomas",
            "lastName" : "Johnson",
            "profession" : "Carpenter",
            "age": 27,
            "education": {
               "Diploma": true
            }
        },
        {
            "firstName" : "Jane",
            "lastName" : "Simpson",
            "profession" : "Teacher",
            "age": 32,
            "education": {
                "Masters Degree": true,
                "College Degree": true,
                "Diploma": true
            }
        }
    }
  }
]
```

If I only want to capture, say `firstName`, `lastName`, and `education` and place each client in a new, empty object `collectedData` as their own individual objects, how would I go about doing that?
Assuming the EXTERNAL DATA is held inside a variable called `data`

1. I've tried the spread operator `collectedData = {... collectedData[i], ...data[i]}`, but it doesn't add each as new objects
2. I've tried using `new Object();` each time I loop through, but I'm not sure how the left-hand side is supposed to look when there are thousands of objects from the external JSON file.
3. I've tried `Object.assign()`, but with no luck

I know I'm overthinking it, but does anybody have an idea even for what direction to go in? I feel burned out.

Would eventually look like this:

```
collectedData = {
  {
    "firstName": "Thomas",
    "lastName": "Johnson",
    "education": {
        "Diploma": true
     }
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Jane",
    "lastName": "Simpson",
    "education": {
        "Masters Degree": true,
        "College Degree": true,
        "Diploma": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to go through the `clients` array (which, looks like a typo in your code... I'm assuming it's an array) and get the object the way you want it.

```
const collectedData = clients.map((client) => {
  return {
    firstName: client.firstName,
    lastName: client.lastName,
    education: client.education
  };
});
```

This basically loops through each client and creates a new object for each one with only the properties you want.  Then, a whole new array is returned and assigned to `collectedData`.

Comment: does `.map` only work with arrays? If you have several  objects inside an array, can you still use `.map`?

Comment: @Mitchell The map is for the array... it doesn't matter what's *in* that array.

Comment: Can you pass a function as an argument, like instead of `clients.map((client) =>` we could do something like `clients.map((getClients()) =>` ?

Comment: @Mitchell Yes, what you see there is simply an anonymous function.  You can pass in any other function.